# IoC container that supports async Get and async instance creation

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, async-await, ioc-container

I have recently begun writing a lot of async/await code in C# using ASP.NET and DynamoDB. I had already selected and setup [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) as my IoC container.  From what I can find in the Ninject docs and searching online, Ninject has no specific support for async.  That makes sense since it was written before async/await was added to C#.  However, [an article on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx) about *Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming* recommends an "Async all the way" approach.  Is there an IoC container for .NET that supports an async resolve and registering async factories?  i.e. if it were supported in Ninject, something like `kernel.GetAsync<IMyService>()` which returns `Task<IMyService>` and a register method like `kernel.Bind<IMyService>().ToMethod(ctx => factory.CreateAsync())` where the `CreateAsync` method returnes a `Task<MyService>`,

#### Example/Why this is needed

I actually had a deadlock in my ASP.NET async code because I was forced to block on async code (to understand why this happens, see [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)).  I have worked around it with `.ConfigureAwait(false)` but it is recommended to do both to prevent problems.  Also, I was forced to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` in one place where it can't be proved that I don't need the context because I am invoking a delegate that could possibly use the context in the future.

I have a user repository that is async because it accesses my data store.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    Task<User> GetAsync(Guid id);
}
```

I registered the current user as a dependency so I would be able to access information like name, email and do security checks.

```
kernel.Bind<User>().ToMethod(GetCurrentUser).InRequestScope();

// The implementation of GetCurrentUser
public static User GetCurrentUser(IContext context)
{
    var repository = context.Kernel.Get<IUserRepository>();
    var currentUserId = /* get current user id here from HttpContext.Current */;
    return repository.GetAsync(currentUserId).Result; // blocks until the user is loaded 
}
```

This code was deadlocking on the `.Result`.  What I really needed was to be able to return `Task<User>` from `GetCurrentUser` and have Ninject correctly handle it with async code.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you would use this... Obviously you're not using it with constructor injection, since you can't really do that asynchronously.  Are you calling GetService?  That's service location, and considered an anti-pattern.  But, even so I would really not recommend doing database access, or anything that could block within your IoC container.  IoC should only resolve methods, not do work itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no IoC containers that support `async`. I think that better IoC and mocking support for `async` is the next logical step in the plan for `async` world domination.

If your user repository can be *created* synchronously, then of course you can use that directly:

```
var user = await context.Kernel.Get<IUserRepository>().GetAsync(currentUserId);
```

However, anything asynchronous does have to be done "outside" the IoC container. I have a blog post on [`async` constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) and an MSDN article on [`async` services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn683795.aspx) that show the best ways of handling these situations today. Hopefully this will change in the near future with true IoC `async` support.

Comment: Any news on true IoC async projects?

Comment: @donttellya: AFAIK none of them have supported this yet. It would be a significant change for all their users. Most likely, we'll just be injecting factories for a while (meaning the *factory* is resolved by the IoC and that has an asynchronous creation method).

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a compile time IOC container utilizing source generators which has support for async resolution.

Try it out at https://github.com/YairHalberstadt/stronginject.

Answer (score -1):

You could use my library [AsyncContainer](https://github.com/RafaelSalguero/AsyncContainer) which supports asynchronous dependency injection:

**Register an async factory**

```
public static async Task<EmailService> EmailServiceFactory() 
{
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return new EmailService();
}

//...
var container = new Container();

container.Register<IDatabase, Database>();
container.Register<IEmailService>(EmailServiceFactory);
```

**Async solve instances:**

```
var instance = await container.GetInstanceAsync<NotificationService>();
```

Comment: the github link 404s